# Flatten API JSON response containing nested structures including a GeoJSON to a GeoDataFrame while keeping the GeoJSON geometry as is

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas, shapely, fiona

#### TL;DR:

I have a JSON response from an API that I'd like to convert to a [GeoDataFrame](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html). But some of the attributes in the response structure are nested dictionaries, including a [GeoJSON](https://geojson.org/) object and if I flatten them, the GeoJSON itself also got flatten, and therefore GeoPandas is not having a proper geometry to deal with when building a GeoDataFrame.

#### Detailed example

Here's a reproducible example in Python 3:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

res='''
    {"results": 
        [{"geometry": 
            {"type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": 
                [[[2486000.0, 1109000.0],
                [2486000.0, 1110000.0],
                [2487000.0, 1110000.0],
                [2487000.0, 1109000.0],
                [2486000.0, 1109000.0]]]},
            "layerBodId": "layer.metadata",
            "bbox": [2486000.0, 1109000.0, 2487000.0, 1110000.0],
            "featureId": "2001",
            "layerName": "Einteilung Raster",
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "2001",
            "properties": {"resolution": "10", "datenstand": "2020", "label": "2001"}}]
    }
'''

data = json.loads(res)['results']
G = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.json_normalize(data))
print(G.columns)
```

The last command prints:

```
>>> print(gdf.columns)

Index(['layerBodId', 'bbox', 'featureId', 'layerName', 'type', 'id',
       'geometry.type', 'geometry.coordinates', 'properties.resolution',
       'properties.datenstand', 'properties.label'],
      dtype='object')
```

So, [`pd.json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) [works fine](https://towardsdatascience.com/all-pandas-json-normalize-you-should-know-for-flattening-json-13eae1dfb7dd) here, but it also affects the geometry, which is a GeoJSON object, hence a dictionary. So it's also split apart. The direct consequence is that my GeoDataFrame has no valid geometry column.

In order to fix this, I need to go for some "ugly" workaround such as:

```py
from shapely.geometry import shape
g = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data)['geometry'] # cut off the geometry column and save it
gdf = pd.concat([G, g], axis=1) # concatenate it to the original dataframe
# shapelyfy it so that GeoPandas knows what to do with it
gdf['geometry'] = gdf['geometry'].apply(lambda x: shape(x))
print(gdf.columns)
```

This gives me a valid geometry columns now:

```py
>>> print(gdf.columns)

Index(['layerBodId', 'bbox', 'featureId', 'layerName', 'type', 'id',
       'geometry.type', 'geometry.coordinates', 'properties.resolution',
       'properties.datenstand', 'properties.label', 'geometry'],
      dtype='object')

>>> gdf.dtypes

layerBodId                 object
bbox                       object
featureId                  object
layerName                  object
type                       object
id                         object
geometry.type              object
geometry.coordinates       object
properties.resolution      object
properties.datenstand      object
properties.label           object
geometry                 geometry
dtype: object
```

But the other geometry related columns from the dummy flattening are now redundant, so I have to do some cleaning in order to get a clean GeoDataFrame. It's especially true if you want to dump this GeoDataFrame to a file, for example a GeoPackage otherwise it (I think it's a [well known](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/365) [fiona](https://fiona.readthedocs.io) related issue) complains about the presence of a list:

```py
gdf.to_file('/tmp/geopackage.gpkg', driver='GPKG')
```

=>

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-60-43028b34fe1f>", line 1, in <module>
    gdf.to_file('/tmp/geopackage.gpkg',driver='GPKG')

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py", line 746, in to_file
    _to_file(self, filename, driver, schema, index, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/geopandas/io/file.py", line 257, in _to_file
    colxn.writerecords(df.iterfeatures())

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fiona/collection.py", line 361, in writerecords
    self.session.writerecs(records, self)

  File "fiona/ogrext.pyx", line 1291, in fiona.ogrext.WritingSession.writerecs

  File "fiona/ogrext.pyx", line 466, in fiona.ogrext.OGRFeatureBuilder.build

ValueError: Invalid field type <class 'list'>
```

#### Question

So, is there a (better) way to convert a JSON response containing some complex nested structures, *including* a GeoJSON object, into a GeoDataFrame by flattening all complex structures *except* the GeoJSON object so that GeoPandas is directly having a proper and valid geometry colum?

Comment: I wondered if the max_level parameter of pandas.json_normalize would be useful, e.g. max_level = 0. But then that leaves the non-geometry structures denormalized e.g. bbox. So ... good question ...